# operator T() not used in assignment

Tags: c++, qt, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution, conversion-operator

I am a bit confused by this. Lets assume I have a helper class `Data`

```
class Data
{
public:
    Data(const QVariant &value) : m_Variant(value) { }
    operator QString() const { return m_Variant.toString(); }

private:
    QVariant m_Variant;
};
```

then when I do this:

```
Data d("text");
QString str = d; //str becomes "text"
```

it works but when I continue to do:

```
Data d2("text2");
str = d2; //does not compile
```

it fails complaining:

```
ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QString' and 'Data')
candidates are:
...
QString &operator=(const QString &);
QString &operator=(QString &&);
QString &operator=(const char*); <near match>
    no known conversion from Data to const char*
QString &operator=(char);
```

But even providing

```
operator const char*() const;
```

does not help. The message about conversion just disappears and the error remains the same. Is there a way to solve this other than adding

```
QString &operator=(const Data &data);
```

to `QString` or calling explicitly

```
str = QString(d2);
```

?

I am confused because the compiler clearly deduced correctly that the left operand is a `QString` and it is apparently trying to call conversion from `Data` to what would one of the `QString`'s `operator=`s accept but even if such conversion is defined it still does not work.

**EDIT:**
The problem seems to come from multiple definitions of different `operator T()` members. In this case `operator int()`.

Comment: the first "correct" assignment, shouldn't it be `QString str = d;` instead of `QString str = Data;`?

Comment: What is `Data`? Could you provide minimal code for this class?

Comment: @Gombat Fixed the typo and provided skeleton of Data. In my app the data is not a QVariant but actually a rapidjson value but for the sakes of simplicity I used QVariant in the example.

Comment: It compiles for me. See my test code [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58f73dd40d52c3c1976d)

Comment: I am not sure why this isn't working but I can tell you `QString str = d;` is calling the constructor and not the assignment operator like `str = d2;` does

Comment: @Gombat Yes this does compile but add this line: str = d2; below line 16 and it won't.

Comment: It compiles with gcc even with the assignment operator `str = d2;`

Comment: @Resurrection: Try it once to compile in debug please, to see whether its [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) or not. Yo might try this example, too: http://cpp.sh/8ag6

Comment: @Resurrection. I added `str=d2` below line 16 and it makes no difference. Did you try to compile it minimalistic in a new project without your includes in your main.cpp you are working with?

Comment: I have found out that the problem is providing multiple conversion operators. If I removed my operator int() it started working.

Comment: The reason it didn't work with multiple conversion functions (`operator X`) is that they are not ranked by overload resolution, since they do not convert to the same type (`QString` and `int`). The type of the lhs of the assignment is irrelevant for overload resolution, since this case only considers several member functions (of the name `operator=`).

Comment: For the construction, you need to end up with an object of type `QString`, and the `operator int` isn't viable because that would require two user-defined conversions (`Data` -> `int` -> `QString`).

Comment: @dyp Why is this not an issue for the constructing assignment of the QString as well? Or is it that QString str = d; is actually QString str(d) while there is no such thing happening for the str = d? Anyway, the only practical solution is most likely str = QString(d) explicit, right?

Comment: Both `QString str = d;` and `QString str(d);` are *initializations*, the former being *copy-initialization*, the latter is *direct-initialization*. There are some subtle differences between them, but they're very similar. `str = d;` OTOH is assignment, which, for class types, is essentially a function call just like some `str.assign(d);`. -- There are several solutions, such as making some conversion functions `explicit`, or removing all but one, or the workaround you've suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't got access to an online compiler with the Qt libraries, but here's what I pieced together from the public documentation of `QString` and `QVariant`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct QString 
{
    QString() = default;
    QString(QString const&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    QString &operator=(const QString &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return *this; }

    QString(char const*)  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    QString &operator=(const char*) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return *this; }

    QString(char)  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }    
    QString &operator=(char) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return *this; }    
};

struct QVariant
{
    QVariant(QString const&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    QVariant(char const*)  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

struct Data
{
    Data(QVariant const&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    operator QString() const  { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return QString(); }
    operator int() const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return QString(); }
};

int main()
{
    Data d("text");
    QString str = d;

    Data d2("text2");
    str = d2;
}
```

**[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe0252b7c357cdf9)**

The **direct-initializations** of `d("text")` and `d2("text2")`, convert `char const* -> QVariant` through the constructors

```
QVariant::QVariant(const char*)
Data::Data(const QVariant&)
```

The **copy-initialization** `QString str = d` elides a call to the `QString` copy constructor on a temporary `QString` object produced by

```
Data::operator QString() const
```

Now for the bug: the **assignment** of `str = d2` tries to match the various assignment operators `QString::operator=` overloads to your `Data` argument. Once `Data` has multiple conversion operators (to `QString` and to `int` e.g.), you will get an overload resolution ambiguity because `QString` has both the regular assignment `operator=(QString)` as well as the `operator=(char)` (which can take `int`).

**TL;DR** there is only one route for construction: `char const* -> QVariant -> Data`. But there are two routes `Data -> QString` and `Data -> int -> char` that lead to a valid argument for the assignment operator.

Fix: use `explicit` conversion operators in your own code (or remove one or more of them).

Comment: Full explanation of what is the problem here. I will add that for solutions see the last comment by @dyp to the OP.