# Conversion operator for std::string fails to work with assignment

Tags: c++, conversion-operator

I am using a proxy type to defer the work until the result is assigned to a variable, it works by using conversion operators on the proxy type. When adding an conversion operator overload for `std::string`, it works for string construction from proxy, but fails to compile for assignment, with the following error message:

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator='

While this question is similar to the one at [operator T() not used in assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32651971/620438), solution there is not applicable here since I am also using templated conversion operator.

Below is the snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Proxy
{
    template < typename T >
    operator T ()
    {
        T res;
        std::cerr << "Converting to T: " << typeid( T ).name() << "\n";
        return res;
    }

    operator std::string ()
    {
        std::string res;
        std::cerr << "Converting to string\n";
        return res;
    }
};


int main()
{
    struct Foo {};

    Proxy proxy;

    bool b = proxy; // Construct, works
    b = proxy;      // Assignment, works

    Foo f = proxy; // Construct, works
    f = proxy;     // Assignment, works

    std::string s = proxy; // Construct, works
    s = proxy;             // Assignment, this line fails to compile <<<<<

    return 0;
};
```

How can this proxy be made to work with the string assignment?

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: Nice riddle. Interesting.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Here is the godbolt link that has the error https://godbolt.org/z/Vagzj9

Comment: Is there a reason you can't copy/paste the error into your question for when the link goes bad or your comment is deleted?

Comment: It seems to be connected with the fact that `std::string` has several overloads for `operator=` since the problem persists even if one removes `operator std::string ()` from `Proxy`, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/HuLEMDf6Q61LSWsQ

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a `static_cast`?

Comment: @Mike Lui, there is more than one data type that can be cast to an `std::string`.

Comment: Replace conversion operator with a function `void convert_to(string &target)`. and replace `s = proxy` by `proxy.convert_to(s)`.

Comment: when construction of std::string works, why not use in in assignment: `s = std::string(proxy);` ?

Answer (score 1):

> How can this proxy be made to work with the string assignment?

The compiler is unable to tell what conversion you want.  It could be anything that can be used to construct an `std::string` - `char`, `char *`, `std::string`, ...

So the solution is to tell the compiler what you want.  Make an explicit operator call:

```
s = proxy.operator std::string();
```

Comment: The *preferred* solution to invoke a specific conversion operator is to use a typecast, don't call the operator directly: `s = (std::string) proxy;` or better: `s = static_cast<std::string>(proxy);`

Comment: The entire reason for using proxy is deducing result type so it is not explicitly typed by the user.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Why don't you just try that yourself ?

Comment: @MustafaSerdarŞanlı, In that case you should just ditch the whole idea.  How can the compiler possibly know which overload to use ?

Comment: Yes, when I tried your code, I was not sure enough to answer, myself, because I do not know all the rules of template-parameter deduction (and because I am an old Perl programmer where the left side of an assignment delivers context to the right) but I did seem to find the same problem @SidS has found. I tried to make a template specialization, anyway, just to see what the compiler would do, but had no luck. One doubts that you can do what you want. This isn't Perl. The compiler does not know the type.

Comment: @SidS my current idea is limiting the templated function via enable_if, so the proxy type can't be casted to initializer_list etc. leaving only one overload which can be used for std::string.

Comment: @SidS [I did, actually](https://www.ideone.com/v8co09). Using SFINAE to disable `operator T()` for types that can construct `std::string`, leaving just `operator std::string` for *implicit* string assignments, works fine. But, *explicit* casts were still ambiguous due to `operator std::string` returning a temp `std::string` that satisfies both copy and move constructors of `std::string`, and I couldn't figure out a way around that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Right, so the "*preferred* solution" simply doesn't work.

Comment: @SidS *in general*, it usually does. But in the specific case of `std::string`, `std::string` has so many different constructors and assignment operators that `operator T` can satisfy, and even has a templated constructor in C++17 that can take a `Proxy` itself, there is just a whole lot of ambiguities going around. It would probably be better in this case to remove `operator std::string` completely and have `operator T` detect when `T` is `std::string`. Or, don't allow `Proxy` to convert to `std::string` at all. Add a separate `toString()` method, or specialize `std::to_string()` for `Proxy`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Or, tell the compiler explicitly what you want it to do.